# Is there a D&D 3.5e feat that's the opposite of Power Attack?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats

I'm looking for a feat that does the opposite of power attack, if one exists, in DND 3.5. A friend of mine is playing a rogue and would like to use such a thing in conjunction with sneak attacks. I couldn't find one, but the general gist of what I'm looking for is the ability to trade damage for bonuses to accuracy rolls. Does such a feat exist? If so, in what sourcebook? My collection is limited but I'd like to at least be able to look online.

Answer (score 7):

[Accurate Attack](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Accurate_Attack_(3.5e_Feat)) is in the Net Book of Feats (non-canon)

> **Accurate Attack [General, Fighter]**
> You can sacrifice one attack for greater accuracy on the next.
> Prerequisite: Base attack bonus +6
> Benefit: When making a full attack you may forgo all but the first attack to receive a +2 bonus to hit for each attack you have forgone.
> Special: You can take this feat up to four times. Each time you take it after the first you increase the bonus for each attack sacrificed by 1 (to a maximum of +5).
> Example: A 13th level fighter has three attacks in a round with base attack bonuses of +13/+8/+3. The fighter chooses to use Accurate Attack and make a single attack with a base attack of +17 (+13, +2 for each of the two tertiary attacks not taken).
> A fighter may select Accurate Attack as one of his fighter bonus feats.

---

You may also want to consider *Weapon Finesse*, which allows you to add Dex bonus *instead of Str bonus* to hit - this will help if your Dex bonus is higher than your Str bonus (as is the case for most Rogues), but **only for light weapons**.

---

But this sounds like almost exactly what you're asking for:

> **Precise Strike**
>
> (from Dragon Compendium)
>
> [General]
>
> You are skilled in finding your opponent's weakness and striking where it hurts most.
>
> Prerequisite:
> DEX 13, Ability to sneak attacks
>
> Benefit:
> When making an attack that would qualify as a sneak attack, you may take away any number of dice from your sneak attack damage and add a +2 circumstance bonus on your attack roll for each die reduction you make. You may convert as many of your dice from your sneak attack damage as you wish in this manner. However, if you make more than one sneak attack during a round and are using this feat, you must convert the same number of dice for each one.

Comment: It's worth noting that you're trading ~3.5 damage for a +2 attack bonus, so the exchange is less than ideal. (Not that sacrificing AC is a very good idea either, unless the enemies are hitting you anyways.)

Comment: Power attack has established that +1 to hit is worth 2 damage, so I'd say that's getting off with a discount.

Comment: @mxyzplk Isn't power attack 1 for 1?

Comment: Ah, you're right, in 3.5.  In Pathfinder it's -1 for +2 (+50% for two-handed, you can only proc it once for every +4 in your BAB).

Answer (score 1):

D&D has a certain idea that heavier and more powerful attacks are less accurate -- less controlled. To an extent, that is true to real life experience. And if one can sacrifice control for power, Power Attack seems like it should have a complementary feat which allows you to sacrifice power for control.

**RAW**

As far as the rules as written go, there is not much.

You mentioned that your friend is playing a Rogue. That means that this feat, [Precise Strike](http://dndtools.eu/feats/dragon-compendium--109/precise-strike--3387/), may be very relevant to his interests. It is featured in Icewind Dale II, if you are familiar with that Black Isle D&D cRPG. Effectively, it allows you to sacrifice sneak attack dice for +2 attack bonuses.

Beyond that, I believe you have to move into the realm of **Homebrew**.

It seems fairly simple to make a homebrew feat for this.
Power attack is as follows:

> *Power Attack* [General] Prerequisite Str 13.
>
> Benefit: On your action, before making attack rolls for a round, you
>   may choose to subtract a number from all melee attack rolls and add
>   the same number to all melee damage rolls. This number may not exceed
>   your base attack bonus. The penalty on attacks and bonus on damage
>   apply until your next turn.

To make a totally balanced equivalent, there only needs to be a few changes:

> *Precise Attack* [General] Prerequisite **Dex** 13.
>
> Benefit: On your action, before making attack rolls for a round, you
>   may choose to subtract a number from all melee damage rolls and add
>   the same number to all melee attack rolls. This number may not exceed
>   your maximum damage output. The penalty on damage and bonus on attacks
>   apply until your next turn.

Granted, this new feat *is* a homebrew, so it does not fit into the game seamlessly (is not a prerequisite for anything else, for example). However:

1: It's what you are looking for.

2: It's balanced and logical.

3: It's easy to remember and doesn't use weird mechanics.

Comment: Indeed a nice idea.

Comment: This feat is...dubious at best. For one thing, if you're relying on additional effects that don't count as weapon damage you can subtract all your damage, deal 1 damage since you can't deal less than one, and deal whatever damage you're applying alongside weapon damage. For example, picking up a Bastard Sword to throw around 10+str+str+bab attack rolls. At the low end of optimization you could have a Swordsage running around throwing their fire-based maneuvers with a +10 attack bonus. Someone with a friend who uses Dragonfire Inspiration could do similarly.

Comment: Then cap the bonus with your Dexterity modifier, or make 0 damage possible.

Comment: This feat should specifically say that you cannot use it with 
Power Attack, otherwise a berserker in frenzy with a two handed weapon would be able to spend attack and get damage back at two to one, then spend the damage to get full attack (or more) back.

Answer (score 1):

Kingdoms of Kalamar Player's Guide has the Unerring Strike feat which is EXACTLY the opposite of Power Attack and also what you are looking for. Note that Kalamar books are technically 3rd party. [image]

Comment: It would be important to note that *Kingdoms of Kalamar* is a 3rd-party product. Aside from games set in Kalamar, it will be relatively rare for it to be available.

Comment: @KRyan Third-party product, yes, but the *Player's Guide* is an *officially-licensed* third party product that bears the Wizards of the Coast seal—that's meaningful to some folks. (Also, the feat Unerring Strike is subject to the *Player's Guide* errata and possibly *The Kingdoms of Kalamar Player’s Guide v3.5 Adapation* document and was further updated to *3.5* by *The Player’s Guide to the Sovereign Lands*, but these latter two products lack the Wizards of the Coast license and seal. These details, too, are meaningful to some folks.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan Sure; still should be noted.

Comment: I was actually unaware that Kalamar was 3rd party. I was under the impression that it was simply another realm like grey hawk, eberron, and faerun. I'll add it in though.

Answer (score 0):

The **War Chanter 3** lets your allies reduce their AC in exchange for an attack roll bonus. Found in **Complete Warrior**; only useful for you if you can talk your bard into taking levels in it. It's a pretty cool PrC anyways—the capstone lets the bard give everyone within 60 feet the same BAB as that of the highest ally within that area. If one of you has Leadership this is definitely worth it.

The [Style] Feat **Inlnidl School** allows one to sacrifice their shield bonus to AC in exchange for half that as an attack bonus. Light weapons only, and it requires both Combat Expertise and Weapon Finesse. Found in **Drow of the Underdark**.

**Knowledge Devotion might** be a good feat for him if he has lots of knowledge skills (since he's a rogue, this would probably only be useful for Humanoids and whatever skill he chooses from Knowledge Devotion.) It gets him a bonus to attack and damage rolls based on a (free action) knowledge check, and is found in **Complete Champion.**

**Reckless Offense** lets you subtract -4 from AC and gain +2 on the attack roll, but it doesn't scale up so I don't recommend it. Found in the **Expanded Psionics Handbook** (it's also in the SRD).

**Chosen Foe** is found in **Drow of the Underdark**; you gain a +1 bonus to attack and damage against one foe, -2 on attack and AC against any others for the turn.

I can't think of any others at the moment; however, your rogue would probably appreciate a pair of Gloves of the Master Strategist. They cost 3,600 GP, are functionally identical to Gloves of Storing, and **give true strike 1/day**. They are found in Ghostwalk while 3.0 material, the book has been updated to 3.5. The only change to the gloves is that it should say 'faint transmutation aura' before the caster level.

Comment: -1, as none of these options allow you to take a penalty to damage in exchange for greater accuracy, which is what the OP asked for.

Comment: Save for precise strike those options don't exist in 3.5. Heck, sneak attack is probably the reason those options don't exist at a 1-to-1 ratio.

Comment: Have you considered making that an answer? It would be more on-topic than this one.

Comment: Eh, the only situation in which I would recommend Precise Strike is if all your opponents are immune to sneak attack by virtue of their type, or if a) Wraithstrike is banned and b) you regularly have problems hitting your opponent's AC.